# Remote Registry Acces (No WinRM)

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to explore and pull values from a remote registry with the RegistryRemoting service. Here is my code:

```
$Computername = "ComputerEx"
$RegPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers"
$Registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',"$Computername")
$RegistryKey = $Registry.OpenSubKey("$RegPath",$True)
$PrinterKeys = $RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames();
```

I need to sort through the returned subkeys for the "port" value being set to something like "USB" and return the subkey that contains that matching value.

Comment: Hello. What’s your actual question?

Comment: So far, I am only able to grab a list of subkeys (the list of printers they have added).  I would like to dig into each subkey to find which ones contain the "port" value similar to "USB", but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: [The registry via PS can be treated like a normal drive](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Powershell+registry+drive%27&t=h_&ia=web). This is well documented in the help files, on SO, and all over the web. So, just use the Get-ChildItem cmdlet, to the target hive of your choice. [You can setup and use PSRemoting, even without WinRM](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+remoting+without+winrm%27&t=h_&ia=web).